# How to get the sequence counts (in fasta) with conditions using python?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

I have a fasta file (fasta is a file in which header line starts with `>` followed by a sequence line corresponding to that header). I want to get the counts for sequences matching TRINITY and total sequences that starts with `>K` after each `>TRINITY` sequences. I was able to get the counts for `>TRINITY` sequences, but not sure how to get the counts for `>K` for corresponding `>TRINITY` sequence group. How can I get this done in python?

myfasta.fasta:

```
>TRINITY_DN12824_c0_g1_i1
TGGTGACCTGAATGGTCACCACGTCCATACAGA
>K00363:119:HTJ23BBXX:1:1212:18730:9403 1:N:0:CGATGTAT
CACTATTACAATTCTGATGTTTTAATTACTGAGACAT
>K00363:119:HTJ23BBXX:1:2228:9678:46223_(reversed) 1:N:0:CGATGTAT
TAGATTTAAAATAGACGCTTCCATAGA
>TRINITY_DN12824_c0_g1_i1
TGGTGACCTGAATGGTCACCACGTCCATACAGA
>K00363:119:HTJ23BBXX:1:1212:18730:9403 1:N:0:CGATGTAT
CACTATTACAATTCTGATGTTTTAATTACTGAGACAT
>TRINITY_DN555_c0_g1_i1
>K00363:119:HTJ23BBXX:1:2228:9658:46188_(reversed) 1:N:0:CGATGTAT
CGATGCTAGATTTAAAATAGACG
>K00363:119:HTJ23BBXX:1:2106:15260:10387_(reversed) 1:N:0:CGATGTAT
TTAAAATAGACGCTTCCATAGAGA
```

Result I want:

```
reference   reference_counts    Corresponding_K_sequences
>TRINITY_DN12824_c0_g1_i1   2   3
>TRINITY_DN555_c0_g1_i1 1   2
```

Here is the code I have written which only accounts for `>TRINITY` sequence counts, but couldn't extend it to the bit where it also would count the corresponding `>K` sequences, so any help would be appreciated.
To Run:
`python code.py myfasta.fasta output.txt`

```
import sys
import os
from Bio import SeqIO
from collections import defaultdict
filename = sys.argv[1]
outfile = sys.argv[2]
dedup_records = defaultdict(list)

for record in SeqIO.parse(filename, "fasta"):
    #print(record)
    #print(record.id)
    if record.id.startswith('TRINITY'):
        #print(record.id)
    # Use the sequence as the key and then have a list of id's as the value
        dedup_records[str(record.seq)].append(record.id)
        #print(dedup_records)
with open(outfile, 'w') as output:
#   # to get the counts of duplicated TRINITY ids (sorted order)
    for seq, ids in sorted(dedup_records.items(), key = lambda t: len(t[1]), reverse=True):
        #output.write("{}   {}\n".format(ids,len(ids)))
        print(ids, len(ids))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the correct kind of thinking but you need to keep track of the last header that starts with "TRINITY" and slightly alter your structure:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from collections import defaultdict

TRIN, d = None, defaultdict(lambda: [0,0])

for r in SeqIO.parse('myfasta.fasta', 'fasta'):
    if r.id.startswith('TRINITY'):
        TRIN = r.id
        d[TRIN][0] += 1
    elif r.id.startswith('K'):
        if TRIN:
            d[TRIN][1] += 1

print('reference\treference_counts\tCorresponding_K_sequences')
for k,v in d.items():
    print('{}\t{}\t{}'.format(k,v[0],v[1]))
```

Outputs:

```
reference   reference_counts    Corresponding_K_sequences
TRINITY_DN12824_c0_g1_i1    2   3
TRINITY_DN555_c0_g1_i1  1   2
```

Comment: I’m ignoring the sequences here of course, not sure if that’s what’s wanted

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help.